# Trouble gluing cap on hot water faucet

Tags: faucet, adhesive, hot-water

We have a kitchen sink hot water faucet that has a cap with "Hot" on it to go on the faucet.  We've tried several types of glue for it, but after a few days of usage, the heat the faucet absorbs from the water seems to make the glue useless.

If you look at the photo, you can see the screw that would be under the cap, so I don't want to use anything super-strong that would force us to break the cap to get to that screw.

What kind of glue can we use that will hold this cap in place that won't break down from the heat from the water and will let us, if needed, pry the cap off if we have to get to the screw under it?

[image: faucet with cap]

Comment: fyi:  the knurled metal part that the cap glues to unscrews from the faucet handle.  so you don't ever need to remove the glue.  The more permanent the glue, the better.

Comment: @Bob: I have no idea why I didn't notice that.  We took it off, used what was recommended in the answer I selected, and everything is fine now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try [Araldite](http://www.go-araldite.com/) or [Milliput](https://www.milliput.com/products.html) - both are different types of epoxy, araldite is a two-part paste, milliput is a putty, and the latter is recommended for repairing radiators, so should be plenty heat resistant. The downside to milliput is that it is not especially sticky and also has bulk, so you might struggle to make a thin, solid join. Araldite should have no such issues, but I can't vouch for its heat resistance.

edit: I have just read the remark about having to reach the screw - in which case be wary of Araldite as I have heard of plenty of references to it needing something akin to a small bomb to shift it once it's cured. If you go for this, use a tiny dot that you can easily crack with a little leverage.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if this is a good idea or not, but I wonder if you could epoxy a small cylinder shaped magnet to the cap with the idea being that it would attract to the screw.

Comment: That's an interesting idea.  We'd have to remove the COLD cap and do the same to it, but it could work.